# imagecolortransparent in PHP not working

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I want to change white color in image (http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/radar.gif) to transparent. I think that code looks right, there is no error logs but picture stays unchanged. I double checked if color in image is really white and it is. Please help.

```
<?php
    $im = imagecreatefromgif("http://www.arso.gov.si/vreme/napovedi%20in%20podatki/radar.gif");

    imagealphablending($im, false);
    imagesavealpha($im, true);

    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

    imagecolortransparent($im, $white);

    imagegif($im, './image_radar_tran.gif');
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
<body style="background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;">
    <img src="./image_radar_tran.gif" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
```

To:

```
$white = imagecolorexact($im, 255, 255, 255);
```

And it will work.  The reason is that the color 'white' is already defined in the index of the gif you are using, so you can't allocate a new index for that color.  Instead, using `imagecolorexact`, you get the existing index for the white color to use and can then change it to transparent.