# Dynamically Adding a background color when hyperlinking to a .png file

Tags: php, html, css, image, hyperlink

So I have a bunch of .png files on my website. I'm using .png files because I am laying them over top of other images to create a mockup. I currently have the .png's hyperlinked so on click the user is directed to the .png file directly (ie. "www.website.com/images/theimage.png").

This is all working good and fine, however, some of my .png files have white in them as they are being layered over top of dark background images. So when the user is directed to the .png file, they can't see any of the white areas because the body default background color (or lack there of) is white. Is there a way to dynamically pass a css rule to the body tag on the page that the browser uses to show the .png? I would like to do it using PHP or CSS or something along those lines.

So in the link, I would like to add some data that gets passed to the http://www.website.com/images/theimage.png page that contains a background color to be used. I was thinking maybe something like:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/images/theimage.png?backround=black">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/images/theimage.png" target="background:black">Link</a>
```

I just don't know.

I have Googled for about 30 minutes now and I can't find anything on a trick to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660729/php-change-background-color-to-transparent

Answer (score 0):

Do you dynamically get the filename in that link using PHP? If so, you can achieve it very easily (provided you also manage the css style for the containing div in PHP).

- Add the required background colour to the name of the png file (like `image-000000.png`).  Now the image name contains the preferred background colour when it shows up on the page.
- Parse the name in PHP to get that background colour into a variable (using `substring` or `explode`) like `$imagecolour = substr(imagename,10,16);`
- Change the css rule for the containing element (like `echo style="background-color:$imagecolour"`).

You could also use the html `data` property to pass the background colour from the image container.

If you use javascript or jquery, you could do the same with the id/class of the image container. 
Suppose the colour is in the data element like

`<image src="image.png" data-bgcolour="000000" class="image-bg-element" />`

then

`var newbg = $('.image-bg-element').data('bgcolour'); $('.image-bg-element').css('background-color', "#"+newbg);`

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it by linking to the image file directly. The best option would be to use PHP to output the image and change the background accordingly, so the link would be to a PHP page instead of the image directly. E.G

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/images/show.php?image=theimage.png&backround=black">Link</a>
```

Then in the PHP file do something like:

```
<?php
    if (in_array($_GET['background'], $validBackgrounds) && in_array($_GET['image'], $validImages)) {
    $background = $_GET['background'];
    $image = $_GET['image'];
?>
    <div style="background: <?= echo $background?>">
        <img src="<?=$image?>" />
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**NOTE**: Be very careful to just echo `$_GET` parameters on the page, you would ideally want to add validation first to ensure the image and background is valid and doesn't contain malicious code

Comment: This is kind of a dirty hack. By doing this you are fundamentally changing the server's response to an HTTP response with a `Content-Type: text/html` from what should have been a `Content-Type: image/png`.

Comment: Yes, this is you don't care about the content type of the response and just want to display the image. If the content type matters then you can use GD to create a new image based on the original one with the specific background, but that might be a bit too advanced for beginners